# UA Mystic: Mastery of Force questions

Tags: dnd-5e, psionics, unearthed-arcana

I'm fairly new to D&D (couple months actually) and this is more or less specifically about the ability Move.

1. Does collision damage only apply if the lifted item is dropped? Could you potentially ram it into the target instead?
2. After lifting the object it states it drops after 60 feet. Is this specifically 60 feet away from you? If so, could you use this to makeshift fly?

Answer (score 2):

1. The collision damage is only dealt by dropping. First, the text of the discipline only states that you deal damage by dropping the item, and says nothing about dealing damage by ramming. Second, if we want to get into physics, 60 feet in 6 seconds (1 round) is only approximately 6.8 mph. Even if something as heavy as a car hit you at that speed, you wouldn't be hurt too badly.
2. The text only says 60 feet period, and doesn't forbid you from standing on the item. Therefore, if you wanted, you could certainly stand on the object and "fly" with it, though it's a pretty inefficient way to fly, given that you'll fall back to the ground at the end of the movement. While it's not stated explicitly, a DM could certainly require you to lift your own weight as well. It's worth noting that the Mastery of Air discipline allows something pretty similar (flying with psi and falling at the end of the move) for a lower cost.

Comment: where is this power defined? couldn't find it.

Comment: @Mindwin it's in the latest UA for the Mystic. I think there's been a few rounds of revisions, and I was looking at the latest version in the Dungeon Master's Guild.